# Git clone, Permision denied?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Привет, дали доступ к репозиторию , однако никак не могу клонировать . Ошибка выходит

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:nameuser/namerepos.git
Cloning into 'namerepos'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> git clone git@bitbucket.org:nameuser/namerepos.git
> ```

Вы клонируете по протоколу `ssh`, в таком случае вам необходимо сгенерировать у себя на компьютере пару ключей (приватный и публичный), приватный расположить в USER_HOME/.ssh (по умолчанию), публичный добавить в репозиторий (это делает админ репозитория). Оф. документация bitbucket по работе с [ssh-ключами](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html)

Второй вариант - клонировать по `https` (если это разрешено настройками репозитория):

`git clone https://nameuser@bitbucket.org/repouser/namerepos.git` либо
`git clone https://bitbucket.org/repouser/namerepos.git`
где `nameuser` - вы, `repouser` - владелец репозитория.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй склонировать по HTTP

```
git clone http://bitbucket.org/nameuser/namerepos.git
```

Comment: @Ainar-G Это не ссылка, а пример ссылки. По ней ничего нельзя найти.

Answer (score -3):

Ошибка на мой взгляд на серверной стороне. Обратитесь к тому, кто дал вам доступ.

Ниже мой ответ не совсем правильный с точки зрения безопасности. Я когда-то настраивал свой git сервер для личного использования и подобную проблему решил [GIT и только SSH](https://wiki.dieg.info/git_i_tolko_ssh)

```
find /home/gitsrv -type f -exec chmod 444 {} \;
find /home/gitsrv -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Comment: предложенные команды — вредный совет.